# Safe voltage drop(due to line length) for laptops and router?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

Ahead of working from home this winter, we bought a 2000W inverter/generator to get us through a season that normally has a power outage, or a few.  Attaching this to a couple extension cords, if I have done my AWG/length calculations correctly, the furthest outlet in my setup should drop by 2-3 Volts (out of a standard ~120 AC) in addition to whatever (hopefully)minor variations come out of the inverter.  Mainly I want to make sure this is safe for the laptops/phones (claimed AC-adapter acceptable input voltage is 100-240 on all), but there will also be a router and mini-fridge, perhaps a cheap TV plugged in.  The amperage rating of the cords are well above these loads, I am mainly concerned about the sensitivity of the electronics.  I think this setup will be safe for them, but wanted to run it by those with more EE experience than me!  thanks!

Comment: A few percent volt drop is unlikely to cause damage to your electronics, however some inverters produce less clean or smooth sine wave output than others, and some devices don't respond well to that.  Also note that the mini fridge may pull a short surge when it starts up, so it could briefly cause a "brown out".  The voltage drop, or the amount of  voltage you "lose" over a cord depends on the amount of current flowing on the wire, so make sure you size the wires based on the most current that might flow, rather than simply measuring voltage drop without a load.

Comment: ^^^ This ---- You can't predict voltage drop by knowing the AWG or length.  You need to know something about your load.   If there is no current flowing, there will be "zero" drop.   If it's a heavy load, you can get significant drop.   Not sure where your calculations came from, but it's a bad rule of thumb that whomever gave you.   Tally up your worst-case loads and use that number to find the "real" loss.  I can almost "guarantee" that fridge is going to cause more than 2-3V loss when it's operating unless you're using 12G wire.  Most consumer extension cords are 14-16 or worse.

Comment: Ya, I'm getting 12G wire, and assuming a 10A draw, which should be more than a mini-fridge and couple laptops usually produce.  Should I get 10G?

Comment: Depends on the the length!    But as mentioned previous, when the fridge kicks on, there will be a 'brown out' condition - You've seen this in your kitchen - The lights dim for a moment when the fridge goes "click'.  That's the event that could confuse your sensitive electronics.  Whether or not it will is 100% dependent on the nature of those things, which nobody here could possibly know.   So you could try the 12g, see if you do have any issues.   But it's expensive stuff, and if you're wrong you're buying a big 10g ....  so ...  do you feel lucky?  ;)   For real, 12  is probably fine....

Comment: Copy, thanks!  At least for the start... I think I'll plug in the fridge when the laptops are unplugged...